# Migrate an Extension to Latest Version of Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I have an extension which was built in 1.5 version of Opencart.

Extension Name - VQMOD OPENCART QUOTATION SYSTEM built by a developer called ringaedor!!

Now we need support to migrate the same extension from old version to 2.0 version of Opencart. We received no response from Developer so we decided to do it ourselves.

Is there a tool or a process by which i can figure out what is the area to change in order to make this extension work with the new version of opencart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not any tool to do so.You can do it your self easily if you have knowledge of changes between these two versions. You must take care of compatible vQMod version. And some syntax changes.